# Assign masked value to different row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df =     code       mapper       version  country  range    month              value
1       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-10              8.0
6       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-11              1.0
2       ABC321       PQS          Beta      IND     LOW    2021-10              0.0
3       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-10              1.0
4       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-11              3.0
```

I am masking the row based on a condition and making the value as zero

```
mask = (
    (df.mapper == 'ABC')
    & (df.version == 'Alpha')
    & (df.country == 'USA')
    & (df.range == 'High')
    & (df.month == '2021-10')
)
df.value = df.mask(mask, 0.0).value
```

which makes df as

```
          code       mapper       version  country  range    month              value
1       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-10              0.0
6       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-11              1.0
2       ABC321       PQS          Beta      IND     LOW    2021-10              0.0
3       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-10              1.0
4       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-11              3.0
```

Now I want to add the masked value "8" which is updated to "0" to next month,

```
expected_output =  code       mapper       version  country  range    month              value
1       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-10              0.0
6       ABC321       ABC          Alpha     USA     High   2021-11              9.0
2       ABC321       PQS          Beta      IND     LOW    2021-10              0.0
3       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-10              1.0
4       ABC321       TRR          Delta     MEX     LOW    2021-11              3.0


EDIT

There won't be duplicate rows
```

Comment: It is expected there are duplicated rows like `index=6 and 7`, difference only `value` ?

Comment: There won't be duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

One idea is convert values to month periods, so for match previous or next month use `+ 1` or `- 1` only:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month']).dt.to_period('m')

mask = (
    (df.mapper == 'ABC')
    & (df.version == 'Alpha')
    & (df.country == 'USA')
    & (df.range == 'High')
    & (df['month'] == '2021-10')
)

mask1 = (
    (df.mapper == 'ABC')
    & (df.version == 'Alpha')
    & (df.country == 'USA')
    & (df.range == 'High')
    & (df['month'] - 1 == '2021-10')
)

df.loc[mask1, 'value'] += next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'value']), 0)
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = 0


print (df)
     code mapper version country range    month  value
1  ABC321    ABC   Alpha     USA  High  2021-10    0.0
6  ABC321    ABC   Alpha     USA  High  2021-11    9.0
2  ABC321    PQS    Beta     IND   LOW  2021-10    0.0
3  ABC321    TRR   Delta     MEX   LOW  2021-10    1.0
4  ABC321    TRR   Delta     MEX   LOW  2021-11    3.0
```